# How to preserve paragraph formatting already applied to whole document to automatically apply to newly inserted text in microsoft word document

Tags: ms-word, text-formatting

I am using MS Word 2016 and I applied paragraph formatting to the whole Word document. Basically, I want to set paragraph>Indent and spacing>"Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style".
[image]

After setting this option the documents shrink and now I want this setting to be applied to a new paragraph during copy copy-paste operation.

I tried to use different copy-paste settings but nothing worked. Currently, I am using the below setting.

[image]

Is there any setting that can automatically apply to new text during copy-paste?. Here is a video to demonstrate my problem.

[image]